# JQuery: append/remove required asterisk to required field

Tags: jquery, append, required

Trying to write a JQuery function to append a required asterisk to a required field triggered on condition.  And I thought this .append statement would work but it doesn't.

Jquery:

```
       function checkRequiredField(){
                var someId = $('#Id').val();
                if (someId == 106587){          //value to trigger
                    $('#someNumberField').prop('required',true);
     THIS LINE -->  $('#someNumberField-label').append('<span class="required-indicator">*</span>');
                }else{
                    $('#someNumberField').removeAttr('required');
                    $('#someNumberField-label').remove('<span class="required-indicator">*</span>');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label id="SomeId-label" class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="SomeId">SomeId<span class="required-indicator">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <g:select name="SomeId" noSelection="['null':'']" from=".." value="${106587}" class="form-control" optionKey="id" required="" aria-labelledby="SomeId-label" onchange="checkRequiredField()"/>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label id="someNumberField-label" class="toplabel" for="someNumberField">Number #</label>
        <g:textField name="someNumberField" id="someNumberField" value="${aphis104Instance.someNumberField}" class="form-control" aria-labelledby="someNumberField-label"/>
    </div>
</div>
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please? And what exactly doesn't work? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: the matching `remove` will not work. Remove normally takes no parameters (or can take a selector). it removes the expression to the left (e.g. `$('#someNumberField-label')`)

Comment: I marked the line that I was hoping worked.  Console returns no errors.

Comment: If possible, can post `html` ? Thanks

Comment: added HTML, had to remove some details...

Comment: should also mention that 106587 is the value of a dropdown item that I want to trigger the function.  But had to remove some of that because of org-sensitive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this, it should be working.

```
function checkRequiredField() {
    var someId = $('#Id').val();
    if (someId == 106587) {
        $('#someNumberField').prop('required',true);
        // make sure its getting here... alert("test")
        $('#someNumberField-label').append(
            $("<span>", {"class": "required-indicator"}).text("*")
        );
    } else {
        $('#someNumberField').removeAttr('required');
        $('#someNumberField-label span').remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna have to troubleshoot further on my end maybe?  This doesn't for for me either...

Comment: hey sorry i edited it <span> instead of just span, please tell me what its still not doing.

Comment: when I hit the select option that 106587 is supposed to trigger (verified this in Firebug), the asterisk never shows up on the field its supposed to be appended to

Comment: firebug is showing that the function is undeclared somewhere.  Trying to find out where...

Comment: that sounds more like the problem, the code should have worked once its actually being executed :)

Answer (score 0):

Here a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kLaaq0dc/2/

```
function checkRequiredField(){
            var someId = $('#Id').val();

            if (someId == 106587){         
                $('#someNumberField').prop('required',true);
   $('#someNumberField-label').append('<span class="required-indicator">*</span>');
            }else{
                $('#someNumberField').removeAttr('required');
                $('#someNumberField-label span').remove();
    }

}
```

Comment: Clicking submit multiple times adds the asterisk multiple times